# In Google Analytics, how can we refer to the custom channel groupings via API?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

In Google Analytics, how can we refer to the custom channel groupings via an API call? Is this possible yet and if not is anyone aware of a timeframe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Channel groupings are not available directly via the API. You would have to use source and medium to recreate them yourself. [Here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3297892?hl=en) is an example breakdown for the default groupings.